# How to compute the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-e^{-nk}\right)^n$ for $k>0$ a constant?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am wondering how I can  compute the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-e^{-nk}\right)^n$ for $k>0$ a constant. I want to think L'Hospital's rule would work here but am unable to get it. Is there an easy trick here?

Comment: You can rewrite this as $(1-z^n)^n$ where $0<z<1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Using Bernoulli's inequality

$$1 \geqslant \left(1-e^{-nk}\right)^n \geqslant 1 - n (e^{-k})^n$$

Comment: Two term binomial expansion?

Comment: or Bernoulli inequality

Comment: Oh right, doh.  Close enough XD

Answer (score 2):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:  Apply L'Hospital's Rule**

If one wishes to use L'Hospital's Rule, then one can proceed by writing

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)^n&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{n\log\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)}\tag 1\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}n\log\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)}{1/n}}\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-kn^2}{e^{kn}-1}}\\\\
&=e^{0}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:  Apply Elementary Inequalities and the Squeeze Theorem**

Alternatively, we can use the fact that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities [SEE THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le\log(x)\le x-1 }\tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we have

$$e^{\frac{-ne^{-kn}}{1-e^{-kn}}}\le e^{n\log\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)}\le e^{-ne^{-kn}}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit.

Comment: Can I ask how you went from $\frac{\log\left(1-e^{-kn}\right)}{1/n}$ to $\frac{kn^2}{e^{kn}-1}$?

Comment: Applying L'Hospital's Rule, we get $$\lim \frac{ke^{-kn}/(1-e^{-kn})}{(-1/n^2)}$$Then, just simplify.  ;-))